# error: value of type 'PyObject' (aka '_object') is not contextually convertible to 'bool'

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, pyobject

I am passing a python module to C as a `PyObject`. I want to check to see if this value is NONE in my C code, using this form:

```
int func(PyObject tmp)
{
   if(tmp)
    { 
     // etc
```

I am getting the following error. How can I convert from a PyObject to boolean value, simillar to the way Python's if function behaves. It is worth noting that when `tmp` is a `boost::python::object` variable this command works as expected.

```
ex_program.cpp:72:7: error: value of type 'PyObject' (aka '_object') is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
  if (tmp)
      ^~~
```

Comment: NULL or None? They are very different.

Comment: None. Thank you for the clarification, I have edited my poset to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PyObject_IsTrue` seems to do what you want](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsTrue):

```
int PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *o)

    Returns 1 if the object o is considered to be true, and 0 otherwise. This is equivalent to the Python expression not not o. On failure, return -1.
```

Comment: Does tmp have to be of type `PyObject*`? I am having problems implementing this with tmp as a `PyObject`...

Comment: I overcame the error using `if (PyObject_IsTrue(&tmp))`